# Unable to execute specific servlet in Jetty

Tags: java, servlets, path, jetty, servlet-3.0

My code looks like this-

```
ServletContextHandler root = new ServletContextHandler(handlers, "/", ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
root.addServlet(rootServlet, "/*");
ServletContextHandler test = new ServletContextHandler(handlers, "/test", ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
test.addServlet(testServlet, "/test");
```

I expect that when I go to `/test`, `testServlet` should get executed, but I only see `rootServlet` getting executed. Why is that so?

I am using Jetty 9 and setting up my handlers as-

```
HandlerCollection handlers = new HandlerCollection();
```

and which are then set onto Server -

```
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have You tried to remove asterisk from this line:

```
root.addServlet(rootServlet, "/*");
```

Your `/test` URL pattern matches pattern from the `rootServlet`. So probably all request that begin with slash (`/test` too) are handled by `rootServlet`. 
If it does not help try to change URL pattern for `rootServlet` for something else.